# How do I insert double blank pages

Tags: pdfpages, afterpage

I can insert one blank page successfully with

```
\afterpage{\null\newpage}
```

But I need two?

Comment: Depending on what you're actually trying to do, I'd use `\cleardoublepage`. You should just be able to add another `\newpage` in the hook, though.

Comment: do you really need afterpage?

Answer (score 17):

Writing `\newpage\phantom{blabla}` twice or more will do the job.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please post a fully working example.

Comment: why the downvote?  (a reason really should be given in such a case.)  this actually does answer the question, and it was the question that didn't have an example.

Answer (score 7):

This MWE should left text in page 1 and 4 and two empty pages in the middle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,afterpage}
\begin{document}
\afterpage{
%\pagestyle{empty}
\newpage~\newpage~\newpage~
%\setcounter{page}{2}
}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

If you want lost the page numbers, remove  the `%` before `\pagestyle{empty}`.

To skip the blank pages in the count, remove  the `%` before `\setcounter{page}{2}`

Answer (score 6):

```
\newpage
~\newpage
```

will simply do the trick.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!